# How does the ip command enforces its routing policies?

Tags: linux, routes, linux-kernel, ip

Recently I tried to send some data over a raw IPv6 socket via `sendmsg()`. It failed and returned `EACCES/Permission denied` because I forgot to set any routes or a default gateway on the interface.

During my research for this problem I looked a lot at the source code of `sendmsg()` and the raw ipv6 socket and was under the impression, that each protocol specific `sendmsg()` implementation writes more or less directly to the `skb` (although I never proofed it).

After getting lost in the Linux source so easily I actually have two-four questions:

- At which point is ip enforcing its routing policy? Before the ip packet is written to the `skb`, after that, how is it done?
- Why did I get an `EACCES` errno from `sendmsg()` and not some other error?

Edit:

The destination address wasn't a broadcast address (IPv6 doesn't implement it anyways). So the EACCES didn't came from that.

Comment: All library calls are well documented in the man pages.  EACCESS means "An attempt was made to send to a network/broadcast address as though it was a unicast address." See https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg.   Routing is done on the complete packet when it is sent.

Comment: The IP address was a unicast address. Added this clearification to the question.

Comment: What is the address?

Comment: 2003:6::1 - It is used as anycast address. But I couldn't find any conventions in RFC2460 to distinguish anycast from unicast addresses. Therefore I assumed the EACCES comes from the ip command.
Is my understanding of IPv6 incorrect and it does actually implements broadcast addresses? Or are anycast addresses equivalent to broadcast addresses in sendmsg()?

Comment: multicast is broadcast for IPv6. anycast counts as unicast but routing has to be configured for it. not sure if it counts as a network address.